# Can't post because 'question body does not meet our quality standards'

Tags: support

Good day/night. I wanted to post something at StackOverflow and it was very urgent. I made to use correct grammar (I'm speaking English natively) but I was not allowed to post my question because 'question body does not meet our quality standards'. I read what these 'quality standards' are and my question seems to be alright. But for some reason it is not. Can you tell me what is wrong with it? Here it is:

> Good day/night. Today i found one old tablet of mine. I can not remeber the pattern and i can not remove it. Tried ADB but it didn't have USB debunging on (when doing 'adb devices' list was empty). Tried trough Google Device Manager and still did not succeed. It acts like this tablet never existed. When i look carefully i saw that the google profile picture is an old one of mine. I turned on wifi but i didn't sync it with my new one. Is there any way to unlock it?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question and so would not be suitable fo StackOverflow even if it was fixed

Comment: "I'm speaking English natively" Hmm. I have corrected many spelling and grammatical errors in your post. I left that one alone but a a native speaker would say "I'm a native English speaker" ...

Comment: I see you use the words **very urgent**. Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @rene Hmm. Good point. Will fix it up :)

Comment: @DavidPostill Be careful to wash your hands after what you just polished

Comment: Salutations/tag lines are also unnecessary noise.

Comment: By "salutation" we mean that greetings like "Good day/night" are examples of what the [Tour] means when it says that there should be "no chit-chat".

Answer (score 5):

This probably belongs on android.stackexchange.com. Sites other than SO do exist.

As for the question itself

> I'm trying to access an older tablet (model and make) running android (ideally you add the possible versions) which has a
>   pattern lock setup. I do not remember the pattern, nor am I able to
>   remove it. I've tried ADB - the device dosen't seem to have USB
>   debugging on and Google device manager dosen't have it listed under my
>   current account
>
> It appears to have an older google account picture, and dosen't seem
>   to sync when I turn on wifi. Is there any way to unlock it?

Should work - you've got a lot of information that's not needed and are missing some critical bits like what tablet it actually is